# Dat GUI - size and position of menu (javascript / css)

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I am trying to use [Dat GUI](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) to add some controls to a [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) project.  I really like the look and feel of the controls provided by Dat GUI.  However, I am having some problems positioning the menu within the page.  I really need to centre the menu horizontally and vertically and also set a custom width and height for the menu.  Surely this must be possible?

Currently I am trying the following.  The menu is almost centering horizontally, so something is working.  But it is not centering vertically (its just stuck to the top of the page) and the size of the menu is not changing at all (the width and height parameters have no effect).

Can anyone help me out with this?

javascript:

```
var gui;

var MenuClass = function() 
{
    this.speed = 0.5;
};

var theMenu = new MenuClass();

gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.domElement.id = 'gui_css';

gui.add(theMenu, 'speed', -5, 5);
```

css:

```
#gui_css 
{    
    position: absolute;

    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
to add a `div` which is a container for your dat.GUI element

`<div id="gui_container"></div>`

then in code

```
var gui = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false });
gui.domElement.id = 'gui';
gui_container.appendChild(gui.domElement);
```

and then in styles

```
#gui_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#gui{
  transform:translate(-50%, -75px);
}
```

Note, that `-75px` in `transform:translate(-50%, -75px);` means that `gui.domElement` has no `height` attribute and you set translation by y-axis approximately a half of its height as you see it on the screen.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/mzbohe1L/) example

Comment: Super thank you.  That was what I needed.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Anyone using Nextjs + React =>

<div id="gui_container" className="d-flex justify-content-center" style={{transform:"translate(0%, 75px)"}}></div>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
```

this will center the element horizontally and vertically as long as it has width and heigth or else it will stretch the element.