How to reposition lil-gui?
I am building a small threejs project as a test for a larger project.
There are 3 components:

a full-width, 70px high header containing a centered title and near the left edge a 'hamburger' icon.
a full-width graphic area ('canvas') from the bottom of the header to the window bottom.
a left-side sidebar that slides off-screen to the left (or returns) when toggled with a mouse click on the 'hamburger'.
Currently there is a graphic object (3JS Tetrahedron) centered in the graphic area which can be reoriented under mouse control. All appears to work as planned.
But I want to add a 'lil-gui' control block in the upper right corner of the graphic area, not of the window which overwrites the header block.
I tried giving a value to the GUI creation argument 'container' as document.getElementById('#webgl'); where #webgl is the ID of the canvas element.

Suggestions?
Thanks
I tried giving a value to the GUI creation argument 'container' as document.getElementById('#webgl'); where #webgl is the ID of the canvas element.

Found this related answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523458/dat-gui-size-and-position-of-menu-javascript-css.

My 'answer' is to follow up on the info in the old dat.GUI posting as suggested by prisoner849.
Also: current AI-assisted format is not friendly.
